# Fast incremental searching of files from shell

Tags: shell, filesystems, files, search, tagging

I like the `command-t` script in vim editor that is able to intelligently and incrementally search for files. Is there some similar program that is able to search from shell? It would be great if it would support tagging mode, so that I could search based on tags. e.g.

```
$ fnd -t pictures,cars
```

gives me the list of possibilities and I can type tab and shift-tab and select the picture I want
p1.jpg
p2.jpg
p3.jpg
p4.jpg
`$ fnd -t pictures,cars,porsche`
p2.jpg
p3.jpg
one tag added will narrow the results

I will summarize it : The application should support effective searching. Effective means it supports advanced features as as `incremental`, `search in content`, `tagging` or other clever technique.

thank you for suggestions

Comment: Your description is a bit vague. What do you mean by incremental: that you can start acting on results before it's searched the whole space? Where do the tags come from, who enters them, where are they stored? What kinds of searches do you want to do: on text contents, or also (apparently) other things (archive contents, contents of word processor documents, text in different encodings, …)? How large is the search space (the disk cache will speed up refined searches for a medium-sized space, but you'll need fancier stuff for a large space)? Do you want to build an index beforehand?

Comment: incremental means that the search results change while typing. You can see example in the question where adding one tag narrowed the searched results. I'm not going to implementation in this question but storage is certainly important in that application. The application could offer one or more kinds of intelligent searching but should be incremental search and locate desired files easily (so we don't need to type all path). Search space could be whole partition (similarly as `command-t` which is really clever).

Answer (score 2):

This might not be quite the simple solution you're looking for, but zsh might do what you're looking for. It's a full-on replacement for bash, but features better tab-completion and a lot of other nifty features.

Comment: I'd like to try it. Please write me the commands and switches to use.

Comment: ZSH does a lot of nifty things and you can configure it to do more but at the end of the day it's a shell, not a find tool or search client. I don't think this is relevant to the question, although the question is pretty vague about what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

There's a search tool on Mac devices named "spotlight".I loved this tool and this is what I found.
***Mutate*** is a great application to search throw your computer and web, translate the words using Google and giving some commands like "kill", "Shutdown/Restart/Logout" and "Open URLs in browser".

I love this application mostly because you can customize it by bash scripting :) .

To install Mutate in Ubuntu 15.04/14.10/14.04/Linux Mint 17.1/17 via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mutate/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mutate
```

you can find the scripts here:

```
~/.config/Mutate/scripts
```

[This](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/12/mutate-is-alternative-to-macs-new.html) is the source and I think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) for searching files. The -exec option allows you to search for tags (for example `find dir -exec getfattr -nuser.tagfoo ';'`). You need filesystem suport for getfattr/setfattr. You can also search based on content with `grep -r foo dir` or `find dir -exec grep -q foo ';' -exec getfattr ...` if you want to combine it with "tags".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, then you have what you need with:

```
 mdfind(1)

 locate(1)
```

Would also do what you seem to want, although not as well.